# How to setup a nifi Registry on a Server

Tags: apache-nifi, apache-nifi-registry

I have been able to setup a Nifi Registry locally and connect it to my Local Nifi Cluster.
But i have Nifi Cluster of my organization (which is on a different port) and i want to setup a Nifi Registry for it. Thus i have setup the nifi registry on a server.

Can anyone help me with procedure for doing this